# C# Convert Action to Action<bool>

Tags: c#

I have a class that has the following property:

```
public Action<bool> Action { get; private set; }
```

And I have a constructor that takes `Action<bool>`  as an argument.

Now I want to add another constructor that accepts an object of type `Action`. How can I convert `Action` to `Action<bool>`? The bool-parameter should be true in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Action<bool> action)
    {
        // Some existing constructor
    }

    public Foo(Action action): this(x => action())
    {
        // Your custom constructor taking an Action and 
        // calling the existing constructor
    }
}
```

Now you could instantiate this class in 2 ways depending on which one of the 2 constructors you want to invoke:

1. `var foo = new Foo(x => { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); });` (calls the first ctor)
2. `var foo = new Foo(() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); });` (calls the second ctor)

Answer (score 6):

```
Action a = () => aboolaction(true);
```

Comment: That is converting an `Action<bool>` to an `Action`.  (He needs the opposite)

Comment: You're right, I read the question the other way (the original question was less clear than the one posted now).